# Appending to Second Last element

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the final output
[Output http://img2.pict.com/cc/dc/64/3257730/0/20100330041140.png](http://img2.pict.com/cc/dc/64/3257730/0/20100330041140.png)

My HTML

```
<li id='$id'>TEXT
    <ul class='indent'>
        <li id='$id'>TEXT</li>
        <li id='$id'>TEXT</li>
        <li class='formContainer'> FORM </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I want to append a `li` between `form` after all other `li` So in this example new li will be appended between `Test141` APPEND `Input Box`

The `$id` are db ids of li which are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#$id > li:last').before('<li />');
```

would be your best bet.